# Prove the support of $f$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be an arbitrary sets, and let $f$ be a function defined as $f: S \to [0, \infty)$.

Suppose $sup \{ \sum_{S' \subseteq S} f(s) \mid S' \subseteq S \hspace{2mm} \text{is finite}\} < \infty$

Prove that $supp f := \{ s \in S \mid f(s) \neq 0 \}$ is countable.

I really do not know how to go about this problem so maybe seeing an example will help.

Let us say that $S= (0,1) \cup (1,2)$. Then what would happen if $f(s)=0$ for all $s \in (0,1)$ ? How does this effect $sup \{ \sum_{S' \subseteq S} f(s) \mid S' \subseteq S \hspace{2mm} \text{is finite}\} < \infty$ ??

I am trying to learn some elementary measure theory on my own over the summer so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $\text{supp}f$ is not countable and let $\varepsilon > 0$ *be arbitrary*. What can you say about the set $\{s\in S:f(s)\ge \varepsilon\}$? What then does this say about $\sup\{\sum\limits_{S'\subseteq S}f(s):S'\,\,\text{finite}\}$?

Comment: If $supp f$ is uncountable, can I say that $\{ s \in S \mid f(s) \ge \epsilon \}$ is at most countable?

Comment: Oops sorry about that. I meant to say $\varepsilon > 0$ is arbitrary. What then do you know about that set?

Comment: Well, I guess we could let $f(s)$ be as large as we would like. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to relate this to the fact that $supp f$ is not countable.

Comment: The set would be uncountable. This says then that there are uncountably many $s$ for which $f(s) \ge \varepsilon$. Does this have any hope of having a finite sum?

Comment: Do you mind showing an example of what is happening? I have this in mind. If $S= {1} \cup (2,3)$. Let us say $f(s)=0$ on the interval $(2,3)$.

Comment: This is all well and good but we want to go the other way. I am setting up a proof by contrapositive/contradiction. A direct proof like you want to do is highly inadvisable.